# I am unable to set my string to be encoded in utf-8

Tags: python, unicode

I have a set of strings which will be collected, some with accents (e.g. `é`).
I wish to create a version of each with the basic ascii variety of letter (for a URL).
I have found plenty of other examples of similar issues, and I can get it working like this:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
unidecode(u"Café")
```

However I am interested in applying this to a set of strings, taken from a csv/googledoc/similar.

In this case, my presumed course of action is to declare that they are in unicode with something like this:

```
from_google_doc = "Café"
a = unicode(fromgoogledoc,'utf-8')
```

however this returns an error that utf8 cannot decode the byte 0x82 at position 3.

I tried this:

```
a = unicode("Café",'iso-8859-1')
```

which works, however when passed to unidecode, chops off the `é`.

Apologies if this is elementary, my research/tinkering has gotten me nowhere... I am fairly new to Python and much newer to encoding!

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file and/or the encoding of the strings you're getting from the CSV/googledoc/whatever?

Comment: This depends *entirely* on what encoding was used for the original document. If you get errors with UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, then *those were the wrong codecs*.

Comment: My standard reply to questions of this nature is to point you to  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html, and http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html. Read those *first*, then come back if you have further questions.

Comment: For example, IBM Codepage 437 has `é` as hex code 82; `'Caf\x82'.decode('cp437')` prints `Café`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out what codec was used to produce the inputfile you are parsing.

**All** 8-bit data (which includes files and network streams) have to use some form of encoding to squeeze human language into the limitations of the computer formats used. Your data is encoded too, just not in UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 (latin 1).

Your UTF-8 decoding error message indicates that you have a hex byte 82 at position 3, so lets assume your example really looks like this:

```
from_google_doc = "Caf\x82"
```

[Code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) happens to have `é` at position hex 82, so the above decodes to Unicode cleanly and with expected results:

```
>>> from_google_doc = 'Caf\x82'
>>> print from_google_doc.decode('cp437')
Café
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(from_google_doc.decode('cp437'))
'Cafe'
```

**However**, without more detail about your source documents and associated metadata, it is impossible to tell if that is the correct codec to be used. For one, there is entirely too little information in your post to say what codec is correct, [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) *also* uses codepoint 82 to represent `é`.

The codec is to be determined on a case by case anyway, as it'll depend on how you got the source data in the first place on how you can detect what codec was used.

I urge you to read:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

before you continue, to fully appreciate what a codec means, and how that differs from Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive advice, really appreciated - I will have a play around later and get back to you when I can establish the encoding of the source - but this looks nice and promising.

Comment: Thanks again for the help - Got everything working, turns out input was in latin-1 from the csv, and cp437 when taking from the command line input function.

Answer (score -1):

Define the encoding of your source file using the `# -*- coding: ...` header (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Then, actually use that encoding (in you editor). In Python 2, use

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

and then,

```
from_google_doc = "Café"
```

actually already is unicode type.

Comment: The codec at the top *only applies to Python string literals*.

Comment: ..whereas in my answer "Café" is a Python string literal, isn't it?

Comment: It tells Python how to decode the Python source file, especially when interpreting (unicode or byte) string literals. But it will not help **one bit** when it comes to interpreting the encoding of **external sources**.

Comment: I entirely agree, but in his question the opener also used a Python string literal.

Comment: The OP is talking about *I am interested in applying this to a set of strings, taken from a csv/googledoc/similar*.

Comment: Sorry, but the 'add a PEP 0263 comment at the top' is entirely the wrong answer here. It won't help the OP at all. The OP had string literals as an example of code that worked for them.

Comment: I think we understand each other :-). I was just after the `from_google_doc = "Café"` "however this returns an error" statement of the opener.

Comment: Okay, I agree with you that my answer is not about the opener's main problem: proper interpretation of external source files.

Comment: To me it is entirely clear the OP is simplifying the case and showing what *he* thinks is being read from the source file. Of course, `from_google_doc` could be `'Caf\x8e'` (Mac Roman) *instead*, which could easily explain the problems the OP is seeing.

Comment: Now the supermarket just closed and I still need something to eat for this evening. I should never have written this answer ;-)